# Nested model form fields not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I have a has_many belongs_to relationship between Job and Address

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :addresses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :job
end
```

Inside the Job form I inserted the proper fields for text:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |address| %>
  <%= address.label :label, "Label" %>
  <%= address.text_field :label %>

  <%= address.label :addy, "Address" %>
  <%= address.text_field :addy %>

  <%= address.label :apt, "Apt/Suite/etc" %>
  <%= address.text_field :apt %>

  <%= address.label :city, "City" %>
  <%= address.text_field :city %>

  <%= address.label :state, "State" %>
  <%= address.text_field :state %>

  <%= address.label :zip, "Zip code" %>
  <%= address.text_field :zip %>

  <% end %>
```

But the fields don't appear. Am I missing something?

EDIT: Added the create action from the Jobs controller

```
def create
@job = Job.new(job_params)
@job.addresses.build
@job.user_id = current_user.id

if @job.save 
    render 'show'
else
    render 'new'
end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your `Controller` look like? Are you building the addresses for the `Job`?

For example, you need to do something like this in your `new` action in your controller:

```
def new
   @job = Job.new
   @job.addresses.build
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I added the create action from my Jobs controller. I had job.addresses.build in my create action. Dough! Thank you very much!